# Counting Clients who meet criteria in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I've built a report in SSRS that is grouped by client. I have count by client of orders so the output would look like this:
[image]

I need to create a grand total expression at the bottom of the report that counts the clients who have orders, so my total would be 2. I'm new to SSRS and am having trouble figuring it out. What is the appropriate way to write my expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Count(IIf(Fields!Orders.Value > 0, 1, Nothing))
```